# how to set bash environment variable based on bash command

Tags: bash

I want to produce random string by command

```
 xxd -l 32 -c 32 -p < /dev/random
 dd1ad9f2deae0af5412e82fbbeb2df6b239e91d49d98638cc5b4bb94aac25463
```

How to set environment variable? Both way below don't wotking

```
export TMP_RPC_PASS=$(echo xxd -l 32 -c 32 -p < /dev/random)
export TMP_RPC_PASS=$(xxd -l 32 -c 32 -p < /dev/random)
```

bash simple freeze after second variant and waiting something, only ctrl-c allow to return command prompt.

Comment: The second one looks OK to me - in what way exactly does it not work?

Comment: @steeldriver, bash simple freeze after second variant and waiting something, only ctrl-c allow to return command prompt

Comment: Second version works for me. Perhaps your test was blocking because entropy was exhausted. Try /dev/urandom for comparison.

Comment: @Tilman, with /dev/urandom all working perfectly. I'm sorry, how to restore my entropy? Or this is not need? Can I working with /dev/urandom always in future?

Comment: Entropy is collected continuously, you just have to wait. If you don't want to wait use /dev/urandom which for most purposes ist just as good.

Comment: Thank you, @Tilman. Post anser please, and I will mark it as solution.

Comment: no need to redirect `<`, xxd takes infile as an argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second version works fine.
The reason it appears to freeze is that `/dev/random` blocks when the system's entropy pool is exhausted, waiting for new entropy to be collected.

To avoid blocking, use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random`.
For most purposes this is just as good.

```
export TMP_RPC_PASS=$(xxd -l 32 -c 32 -p /dev/urandom)
```